# Node: how can i get user informations of the current logged user with jwt

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt, prisma

I have an api and this middleware checks if the user is logged in, and its working fine:

```
export const AuthMiddleware = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    //Get the jwt token from the head
    const token = req.cookies.token
    let jwtPayload;
    try {

        jwtPayload = <any>jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string);
        res.locals.jwtPayload = jwtPayload;
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send();
        return;

    }

    const { clientId, name } = jwtPayload;

    const newToken = jwt.sign({ clientId, name }, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string, {
        expiresIn: "1h"
    });
    res.setHeader("token", newToken);


    next();
};
```

this is the prisma model for the user(client):

```
model Client {
  id         String          @id @default(uuid())
  email      String          @unique
  name       String
  password   String
  created_at DateTime        @default(now())
  updated_at DateTime        @updatedAt
  reviews    ProductReview[] @relation("client")
  adm        Boolean         @default(false) // its false cause be deafult the client is not an adm and the first adm should manage that

  @@map("clients")
}
```

its working fine but i wanna do a second function to check if the current logged client has the field adm as true, so it can validate if the user is adm, anyone has some idea of how can i do that?